# t:saveState does not work anymore after migrating JSF 1.x to JSF 2.x in WebSphere 8

Tags: jsf, migration, websphere, tomahawk, savestate

I have used JSF 1.x with Tomahawk 1.1.9 in my project and I'm now migrating this project to Websphere 8. I have changed the Faces config and `web.xml` configuration.

All components are working fine except of `t:savestate`. I am still using Tomahawk 1.1.9.
Is there any issue in using Tomahawk 1.1.9 version in JSF 2.x application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade Tomahawk to a JSF 2.x compatible one.

In [their download page](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html), pick the one saying "for JSF 2.0" and not the one saying "for JSF 1.2".